# Finding smallest possible dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis

I am trying to find the smallest possible dimension of a vector space V, which has 3 subspaces $S_1, S_2, S_3$. These subspaces have the dimensions of:
$dim(S_1) = 4dim(S_2) = 6dim(S_3)$.
It is also known that $S_1 \cap S_3 = \{0\}$ and that $S_2\neq\{0\}$.
I am not really sure how to approach this question.
But I thought that maybe using this might be a way to start:

$dim(U) + dim(V ) − dim(U ∩ V ) = dim(U + V )$. For the relationship between $S_1, S_3$

To get:
\begin{eqnarray}
dim(S_1) + dim(S_3) - {0} = dim(S_1 + S_3)\\
dim(S_1) = 6dim(S_3)\\
7dim(S_3) = dim(S_1 + S_3)\\
\end{eqnarray}
But I am unsure if this is the right track of working or even how to bring in $S_2$ into this.

Comment: Note that the largest of these vector spaces is $S_1$ and the smallest $S_3$. Use that to find a lower bound then show that it works. For the $S_2$ case, just forget about $S_3$ and ask yourself how large you can make $dim (S_1 \cap S_2)$. What does that imply?

Comment: @CyclotomicField does this mean that the lower bound is Dim($S_3$). And that $dim(S_1 \cap S_2)$ can only be as large as $\frac{1}{4}dim(S_1)$

Comment: @CyclotomicField sorry but how do I go about finding the lower bound?

Comment: To find the lower bound you start by assuming the smallest space is as small as possible without creating a contradiction. So if $S_3$ is zero dimensional, what happens? What if it's one dimensional? You've actually done some of this work already by calculating $dim (S_1 + S_3)$ so you're not that far from finishing.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ok so If S3 is zero dimensional then, S1 must also be zero-dimensional as $7dim(S3)=dim(S1+S3)$. But If it is 1 then S1 will be 6? Also can $dim(S_1 \cap S_2)$ only be as big as the smaller subspace being $S_2$?

Comment: If $S_3$ is zero dimensional, so is $S_2$, but that's a problem. Do you see why? The intersection can be as big as the smaller space (if there is one), or smaller than that. This is because if $S_2 \subset S_1$ then $S_2 \cap S_1 = S_2$.